# probability double-headed

Tags: probability

Question: 9 fair coins and 1 with double head. First I draw a coin and see the face is a head, what is the conditional probability that the next one is the double head one?

Using Bayes theorem, we have 
\begin{align*}
P(D_2|H_1) = \frac{P(H_1|D_2)P(D_2)}{P(H_1)}. 
\end{align*}
I managed to find $P(H_1) = P(H_1|F_1)P(F_1) + P(H_1|D_1)P(D_1) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{9}{10} + 1\frac{1}{10} = \frac{11}{20}$. However, I'm not sure how to compute the quantity $P(H_1|D_2)P(D_2)$ and I need help on this. Thanks.

Comment: $P(H_1 | D_2)$ is ${1\over 2}$. $P(D_2)$ is ${1\over 10}$. Can you see the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

When the second coin will be a double header, then the first coin will be fair.

So the conditional probability for the first coin showing heads up, when given the second coin will be a double header, is ...

> $$\mathsf P(H_1\mid D_2)=1/2$$